# Making an array of dictionaries, with the value of the dictionary also being an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary, discord.js

In my discord bot I am having a array of teams.

if I could declare everything together it would be something like `let teams = [{messageID:players[]}];`  with players being an array of strings of user ID's, teams being an array of dictionaries and messageID being the ID of a message they reacted to.

People join said team by reacting to a message. When they react I want to loop through the array find the messageID that they reacted to, and add their ID to the array of players. I am having problems with where to declare what and how I can index all these values.

Currently I have my teams array declared at the top of my bot, then once a team message has been created, I push the dictionary to my teams array like so:

`teams.push({key: embedMessage.id, value: players[message.author.id]});`

However this does not work because when I want to check values of the teams[x] key/value to check a player is not already in another team etc, it has no idea what players[ ] is? Any help is greatly appreciated.

````
                let agentString = "";
                const name = args[1];
                const language = args[2];
                const noOfPeople = args[3];
                const agents = args[4].split(',');

                for (let x in agents){
                    console.log('checking ' + agents[x])
                    if (agents[x].toLowerCase() === 'reyna'){agentString = agentString + '<@&762024455391936512> '}
                    else if (agents[x].toLowerCase() === 'sage'){agentString = agentString + '<@&762024358105055272> '}
                    else if (agents[x].toLowerCase() === 'phoenix'){agentString = agentString + '<@&762024408168267807> '}
                    else if (agents[x].toLowerCase() === 'raze'){agentString = agentString + '<@&762024426824400919> '}
                    else if (agents[x].toLowerCase() === 'viper'){agentString = agentString + '<@&762024863182618676> '}
                    else if (agents[x].toLowerCase() === 'brimstone'){agentString = agentString + '<@&762024508734963753> '}
                    else if (agents[x].toLowerCase() === 'breach'){agentString = agentString + '<@&762024388014768138> '}
                    else if (agents[x].toLowerCase() === 'sova'){agentString = agentString + '<@&762414403399188481> '}
                    else if (agents[x].toLowerCase() === 'omen'){agentString = agentString + '<@&762024815744778240> '}
                    else if (agents[x].toLowerCase() === 'jett'){agentString = agentString + '<@&762024732660727821> '}
                    else if (agents[x].toLowerCase() === 'cypher'){agentString = agentString + '<@&762024650724737047> '}
                    else if (agents[x].toLowerCase() === 'killjoy'){agentString = agentString + '<@&762024794992410634> '}
                }

                const LFGEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                    .setColor('#b34100')
                    .setTitle('LFG Post')
                    .setAuthor(message.author.username)
                    .setThumbnail('https://cdn.discordapp.com/icons/761878850920644610/0d17b72a31ddaccaf65e9cf14b8d7eed.png?size=128')
                    .setDescription(agentString)
                    .addFields(
                        { name: `Name:`,
                            value: `${name}`},
                        { name: `Language:`,
                            value: `${language}`, inline:true},
                        { name: `Players:`,
                            value: `${noOfPeople}/5`, inline:true},
                    )
                    .setTimestamp()

                client.channels.cache.get(channelID).send(LFGEmbed).then(embedMessage => {
                    embedMessage.react("");
                    let players = [];
                    teams.push({
                        messageID: embedMessage.id,
                        players: players[message.author.id]
                    });
                    console.log(teams); ```
````

Answer (score 0):

To check if a player is already in a team you could just search through the existing players in the `teams` array:

```
if (!teams.find(team => team.players.find(pid => pid === idOfPlayerThatReacted))) {
   // User does not belong to any team
   const teamToAddPlayerTo = teams.find(team => team.messageId === messageIdThatThePlayerReactedTo);
   if (teamToAddPlayerTo) {
      // Existing team
      teamToAddPlayerTo.players.push(idOfPlayerThatReacted);
   } else { 
      // New team
      teams.push({ messageId: messageIdThatThePlayerReactedTo, players: [idOfPlayerThatReacted] });
   }
}
```